# Replace webuzo to cPanel

Tags: cpanel, uninstallation, whm, dedicated-server, reinstall

My client's CentOS 6.7 dedicated server came with Webuzo installed. But he wanted WHM & cPanel to be installed in it.

Can anyone tell me the steps to uninstall Webuzo and install cPanel as i cannot find any websites giving me the steps to uninstall.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not uninstall Webuzo panel from your server, To remove it you need to reinstall  your server OS (operating system)

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Just came out of curiosity, what if i install cPanel even though webuzo is installed. Will it work? do i land in any problems in installing or when using?

Comment: No. You can't not install over webuzo. Cpanel needs a fresh installon of Centos

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following:

```
rm -rf /var/softaculous/apps/exim
rm -rf /usr/local/apps/ 
rm -rf /usr/local/webuzo/ 
rm -rf /usr/local/emps/ 
rm -rf /var/webuzo 
rm -rf /var/softaculous/ 
rm -rf /usr/local/{apps,webuzo,emps} 
rm -rf /var/webuzo 
rm -rf /var/lib/mysql 
rm -rf /var/softaculous 
rm -rf /etc/mysql
```